# Problem to extend array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

i have a problem. I have written a code for extend Array Element, and works fine, but when i iterate over array this show extended functions. I don't know how stop this. 
There is the code...

```
Array.prototype.remove  = function(e)   {var i = this.inArray(e);if(i != -1) this.splice(i, 1);return this;};
Array.prototype.add     = function(e)   {this.push(e); return e;};
Array.prototype.inArray = function(v)   {for(i in this) if(v==this[i])return i;return false;};
Array.prototype.toggle  = function(v)   {this.inArray(v) ? this.remove(v) : this.add(v);return this;};
```

So when i tried this...

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(i in arr)
document.write(arr[i]);
```

this print array values and functions extended. somebody can help me? I can't change the code "for(x in y)" because is many times in many files.

Comment: You're trying to iterate over the **values** in the array, but it's iterating over your custom functions as well?

Comment: You should not use *for..in* with arrays because the order of enumeration is implementation dependent. Most browsers will return numeric keys first in lowest to highest order, but IE will return keys in the order they are added. So you will get lowest to highest only if that is the order in which they were added. e.g. `var i=2, a=[], p;while(i--)a[i] = i;for(p in a) alert(p);' shows 0, 1 in most browsers but 1, 0 in IE.

Comment: *"I can't change the code..."* Sure you can, and you should. The cost of writing faulty code is fixing faulty code.

Comment: *[Waves hand] "You will fix the faulty JavaScript."* OP replies: *"I will fix the faulty JavaScript."*

Comment: @patrick Ta kur pe je lax ne punu isok!

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: If not for Google, I'd have probably been up half the night trying to solve a riddle! :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to read that will explain the situation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Use .forEach() when iterating over an array. It's pretty well supported, including Mobile Safari and Android,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `forEach()` isn't widely supported yet, but it is a good option if your target platforms support it.

Comment: *It's pretty well supported* The only IE that supports it is is IE9. For most public facing websites that is a bit of an issue (unless you monkey patch it, the MDN docs have a good example).

Answer (score 1):

If you must modify the `Array` prototype, you must use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) otherwise it will pick up properties up the prototype chain.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(var i in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        document.write(arr[i])
    }
}
```

You said, however, you don't want to change your `for (in)` loops. Why don't you have an Array utility object? Or just use normal `for` loops? These are `Array`s right? `for (in)` is for iterating over `Object` properties.

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` loops through *object properties* in JavaScript, not *array elements*.  The `for ... in` loops are simply the wrong way to do this.  You've said that you can't change them, but using this syntax to enumerate the contents of arrays is not a recommended practice in JavaScript, for the reason you have just discovered.

You are going to have to rewrite the `for ... in` loops sooner or later.

Comment: Arrays are objects, `for..in` will loop over all array properties, including the ones with numeric names.

Comment: Exactly.  Which means that using `for ... in` as though it were `foreach` from other languages is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array's indexes.-

```
var A=[1,2,3,4,5];

Array.peototype.omega=function(replacer){
  var L= this.length;
  if(L)--L;
  if(replacer!=undefined)this[L]=replacer;
  return this[L]
}

for(var i=0,L=A.length; i<L; i++){
//do something to A[i]
}
```